# Does @property is a way to access the private and protected members inside the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn a object oriented programming. I read different codes regarding `@property`. According to my understanding `@property` is a way to access the private members within a class. What if I replace all the protected and private members as public and skip `@property` decorator.

```
class DataSet(object):
    def __init__(self, MC_Samples, labels):
    assert MC_Samples.shape[0] == labels.shape[0], (
    self._num_samples = MC_Samples.shape[0]

    self._MC_Samples = MC_Samples
    self._labels = labels
    self._epochs_completed = 0
    self._index_in_epoch = 0

    @property
    def MC_Samples(self):
        return self._MC_Samples
    @property
    def labels(self):
        return self._labels

    @property
    def epochs_completed(self):
        return self._epochs_completed
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "private members" in Python, only slightly hidden. You can still access `._labels` directly, for example. So yes, there is no need for properties if you don't need what they have to offer.

Answer (score 2):

There *are not* private and protected properties in python. By convention, variables starting with `_` should be treated as private, but the language does not force it.

Now, regarding properties: In static languages eg. java, you ofter see this pattern

```
class Test {
    int x;
    int getX() { return x;}
    void setX(int value) { this.x = value;}
}
```

These getters and setters *do absolutely nothing* to promote encapsulation. You could just as well write `test.x =5` instead of `test.setX(5)`. However, you have to use them, *just in  case* something changes later.

In python, you use the opposite approach. Prefer to have a public `x`, and write `test.x =5`. Properties are getters and setters that are added later, only if you need them.

So, if your class was initially

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x
```

feel free to write

```
test = Test(5)
test.x = 10
```

If later, eg, you want your `x` to be float, you remove the `x` variable, and add a `x` property

```
class Test:
    @property
    def x(self):
        return float(self._x)

    @property.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = float(value)
```

You have now removed the `test.x` variable, and created two new methods. From now on, when you use `test.x`, or you assign to it, these two methods are called instead. These read/write to an interval `_x` variable, which is the old `test.x` (this is just the most common case though, they could do absolutely anything)

Comment: upvoted. but, if the OP went for ‘__x’ instead, he’d get a fair bit of obfuscation/privacy out of it.  unlike the single leading underscore, there is some actual name mangling going on.  the rest of your points stand.

Comment: @JLPeyret: there is name mangling, but it's still not exactly private, in the sense of other languages. my main point is that in python you can't *force* privacy, you just rely on users of your code to respect it.

Answer (score 1):

`@property` mostly have 2 uses -

1. As an access for protected variables within a class (Encapsulation)
2. As an access for dynamic attribute, when validation / logic is involved. Usually comes in pairs with setters.